# How to store multiple checkbox values in different rows in MySQL db?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have multiple checkbox values as shown in figure:[image: check-boxes for different category]

I know that can store values for single checkbox in DB but situation here is slightly different, so how could I successfully store them in different rows for the same DB.

My table structure is:

```
1.content_table  
 title,description,category_id(fk),course_id(fk),subject_id(fk),content_type_id(fk)  
2.category_table  
  entrance,school,ug,pg  
3.subject_table  
  english,hindi,maths......

4.content_type_table  
   notes,summary,videos,question_bank
```

I have to insert data from shown form in content_table which stores data by category_id,course_id,subject_id,content_type_id.

I have tried the following code which is only working for single checkbox i.e category , so please someone suggest to me how to do it for a different type of checkbox.

My code is:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$url = $_POST['content_url'];

$category = $_POST['category'];

foreach ($category as $cat) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT category_id from category_ref_table where category = '$cat'") or die(mysqli_error());
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     $category_id = $row['category_id'];
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO content_table (title,description,url,category)VALUES ('$title','$description','$url','$category_id')");

 }
```

Comment: Instead saving in diff col, why don't you save it in a single column with `, or ;` separated

Comment: then it will give problem,when i fetch results to show conten to users,i guess

Comment: I don't think so, you can again redeem that string as an array

Comment: what? i did n't get that,

Comment: You should save the fields in a new table  and link it to the user (with columns like: value (checkbox value), type (what checkbox it is), user_id (the user). Don't store it as a comma separated string. That's bad design in a relational database and will give you a lot of headaches later on.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson suggestion is also correct you can store it in a new table. But the option I gave is not hectic as said by @MagnusEriksson. You just have to use `implode and explode` @parvez

Comment: @Ms.Nehal if i store using comma then it will be against 1nf rule

Comment: Then go for another option, which is saving values in diff table, against the user id

Comment: is there any other method apart from that,because i don't want to bring any other table in the play @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @parvez - In my experience, no. If you want to save one to many, you need a new table. The problem with saving them as a comma separated string is that it's not really searchable (you need to do a LIKE, which might give you false positives as "%category1%" will return 'category1' and 'category1*' and so on). Like I said, it will give you headache... :)