# how to store two checkbox values in mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i have multiple checkbox values in my form as shown in figure
[image]

I know i can store values for single checkbox in db but here situation is slightly different,so ho could i successfully store them in different different rows for same db.

my table struture is

```
   1.content_table  
 title,description,category_id(fk),course_id(fk),subject_id(fk),content_type_id(fk) 


    2.category_table  
   entrance,school,ug,pg  
    3.subject_table  
   english,hindi,maths......

   4.content_type_table  
   notes,summary,videos,question_bank
```

i have to insert data from shown form in content_table which store data by category_id,course_id,subject_id,content_type_id

i have tried following code which is only working for single checkbox i.e category ,so please someone suggest me how to do for different type of checkbox.

my code is

```
<?php
include 'includes/dbconfig.php';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
{
echo $title = $_GET['title'];
echo $description = $_GET['description'];
echo $content_url = $_GET['content_url'];
echo $thumb_icon_url = $_GET['thumb_icon_url'];
   $category = $_GET['category'];
   $course = $_GET['course'];
echo $select_subject = $_GET['select_subject'];
echo $select_content_type  = $_GET['select_content_type'];
foreach (array_combine($category, $course) as $cat => $cose) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT category_id from category_ref_table where category = '$cat'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $category_id = $row['category_id'];
    $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT course_id from course_ref_table where course = '$cose'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);      
    echo $course_id = $row1['course_id'];
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT subject_id from subject_ref_table where subject = '$select_subject'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);      
    echo $subject_id = $row2['subject_id'];
    $sql3 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT content_type_id from content_type_table where content_type = '$select_content_type'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3,MYSQLI_ASSOC);      
    echo $content_type_id = $row3['content_type_id'];
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO content_ref_table (title,description,content_url,thumb_icon_url,category_id,course_id,subject_id,content_type_id,login_id)VALUES ('$title','$description','$content_url','$thumb_icon_url','$category_id','$course_id','$subject_id','content_type_id')");

 } 


 }
 ?>
```

Comment: queries in loop make slow your project use joins instead of use multiple queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to store multiple checkbox values in different rows in mysql db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782600/how-to-store-multiple-checkbox-values-in-different-rows-in-mysql-db)

Comment: i still did n't got the feasible answer @Ms.Nehal

Comment: If multiple categories can be stored against a single course/subject then your table design is flawed

Comment: ... And there's so many queries here. Why?

Comment: @Strawberry yes you are right but multiple course be assigned to same category,that's what i'm doing,suggest me some other query

Answer (score 0):

try something like this(array variable)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="entrance">
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="School">
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="ug">
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="pg">
```

Upon using like this you can get the list of checked items as an array.  After that do the required save it in your table.

Comment: i have two array one for category and another for course,for single checkbox array everything is working fine